# Importing an Excel 2003 xml file with multiple sheets into Microsoft Dynamics 2011

Tags: xml, excel, import, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to set up a data map in Dynamics CRM which will allow me to import customer data from a Microsoft Excel 2003 XML file that has multiple worksheets. Each entity information ("Accounts" and "Customers") is stored on a separate worksheet. I've changed the  tag to "Multiple" in the data map xml and added entity maps for customers and accounts, then imported this back into Dynamics.

However, when it comes to perform an import, the CRM software only sees what's on the first worksheet and tries to derive both customer and account data from this one data set. I've tried looking around for people with similar problems but it doesn't seem to be a common issue.

The Excel 2003 XML format supports multiple worksheets. Is it possible to have the import process handle these multiple sheets, or is it simply not supported? I'm capable of editing either the XML code for the data map file or the import data file, but I've not coded any plug ins for Dynamics itself before. Any help you could give me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Dynamics CRM only reads data on the first worksheet. 
Any other sheet is neglected. The best thing to do is to make multiple XML files one for each entity you need to upload. 
This is more structured and then your troubleshooting will be a lot easier if something goes wrong.

Comment: I was worried this might be the case. Thank you for your help. I think it's likely that I'll take a two-sheet approach, but I'll leave this question as unanswered for a little longer to see if anyone has any other suggestions.